# Query to Find Max row based on N fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given the following data:

```
ID Name, Value, TimeStamp
1, 'A', 7.00, 21/12/2017
2, 'A', 5.00, 21/12/2017
3, 'A', 6.00, 20/12/2017
4, 'B', 1.00, 21/12/2017
```

Result I want is:

```
Name, Value, TimeStamp
'A', 5.00, 21/12/2017
'B', 1.00, 21/12/2017
```

I.e. group by Name and take value with latest TimeStamp, if 2 or more have the same TimeStamp take the one with latest ID

I did seem to find an answer that was similar to another post:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Value, TimeStamp
FROM MyTable
JOIN ( SELECT Name, MAX(TimeStamp) As TimeStamp
       FROM MyTable
       GROUP BY Name ) m
    ON MyTable.Name = m.Name and MyTable.TimeStamp = a.TimeStamp
```

This gives me the max timestamp so to get the id, I can repeat the process, i.e. I can use:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    ...
)
SELECT Name, Value, TimeStamp
FROM CTE
JOIN ( SELECT Name, MAX(ID)
       FROM CTE
       GROUP BY Name ) a
    ON CTE.Name = a.Name AND CTE.ID = a.ID
```

However, what happens if I now want to scale it up to 3 fields. Is there an easier way to do this, without experimenting I was thinking recursive CTE. Trying to avoid dynamic sql.

Comment: I just saw another post you could try and join all the fields in question as one consolidated field in the order of priority e.g. 1, 'A', 7.00, 21/12/2017 becomes 'A', and '2017-12-21|1' and 7.00 as 3 fields then do a MAX on the consolidated column, so I might have found a solution

Comment: use row_number() over (order by(timestamp desc, id desc))... sorry on my phone so can't type an answer up yet

Comment: And you'll need to partition by name

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to use the [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) function for this. Below is an example.

#### SQL Example

```
;WITH 
test_data 
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 1, 'A', 7.00, '21-Dec-2017')
    , ( 2, 'A', 5.00, '21-Dec-2017')
    , ( 3, 'A', 6.00, '20-Dec-2017')
    , ( 4, 'B', 1.00, '21-Dec-2017')
    ) tbl ([ID], [Name], [Value], [TimeStamp]) 
)
, 
test_data_order 
AS
(
    SELECT 
          [ID]
        , [Name]
        , [Value]
        , [TimeStamp]
        , EX_ROW_NUMBER = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (
                PARTITION BY 
                      [Name] 
                ORDER BY 
                      [TimeStamp] DESC
                    , [ID] DESC
            ) 
    FROM 
        test_data
)
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    test_data_order
WHERE 
    EX_ROW_NUMBER = 1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=50e0f2488d78d7d1a4c411d9fc1907a1)

#### Results

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Name, Value, TimeStamp
FROM (
    SELECT ID, Name, Value, TimeStamp
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC, ID DESC) AS RowNum
) b
WHERE RowNum = 1
```